# Datatype which never makes sum negative

Tags: java, byte

i am dynamically calculating the size of byte based on existing size and incoming size.But when the values grows beyond the result is becoming negative

```
int i = 65568768;
int j = 2106140544;
System.out.println(i+j);
```

Is there any way i can hold the sum with out losing its sign.I calculate the size array by .length

Comment: For what purpose? What are you actually doing?

Comment: Based on sum of two numbers i need to initialize an byte array of that size.

Comment: The maximum array size is `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 5`, so you will run into that size limit anyway.

Comment: Yes any alternative to byte [] which can grow unconditionally

Comment: Several arrays then, it's easiest if you make all but the last a power-of-two size.

Comment: I can explain you my problem may be you can help.I wrote a custom collector which will collect byte[] from each thread and write it a deflateroutputstream in the Supplier.And in the acumulator i combine all this byte array and write one more byte[].The probelm is when the size of all byte sum increases

Comment: Then why do this at all? Maybe I don't quite understand the problem but it seems like you can just write those separate `byte[]`s to that output stream without ever trying to combine them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143911/discussion-between-pppavan-and-harold).

Answer (score 2):

int has not a enough large capacity.
Try with long by specifying the `L` suffix.

For example :

```
long v = 65568768L + 2106140544L;
System.out.println(v);
```

If you write :

```
long v = 65568768 + 2106140544;
```

you will have the same problem as when the type is not specified the numbers with no floating part are `int` by default.

`65568768` + `2106140544` = `2171709312` 
and `2171709312`   `> 2147483647` (Integer.MAX_VALUE)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**BigInteger**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) instead :

```
BigInteger i = new BigInteger("65568768");
BigInteger j = new BigInteger("2106140544");
System.out.println((i.longValueExact() + j.longValueExact()));
```

**Output**

```
2171709312
```

Comment: But i can i intiate byte[] with long value.even if i cast i would loose the value

Comment: what did you mean @pppavan i don't get you

Answer (score 1):

BigInteger worked for me:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

BigInteger i = new BigInteger("65568768");
BigInteger j = new BigInteger("2106140544");
System.out.println(i.add(j));
```

Output:

> 2171709312

[Javadoc here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).